# No route matches in functional/controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, minitest

I have the following controller test using Minitest::Rails and Rails 4. When I run it, I get an error: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/", :controller=>"foo"}` error, despite it being defined.

The whole point of this is to test methods that are on ApplicationController (`FooController` exists only in this test and is not a placeholder for the question).

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render nothing: true
  end
end

class FooControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  it 'does something' do
    with_routing do |set|
      set.draw do
        root to: 'foo#index', via: :get
      end

      root_path.must_equal '/' #=> 
      get(root_path).must_be true #=> No route matches error
    end
  end
end
```

There a number of similar questions on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but they all refer to the issue of route segments being left out (e.g. no ID specified on a PUT). This is a simple GET with no params, however.

I get the same result if the route is assembled differently, so I don't think it's the `root_path` bit doing it (e.g. `controller :foo { get 'test/index' => :index }`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was much simpler than expected:

```
# change this:
get(root_path)

# to this
get(:index)
```

The `with_routing` method works fine to define the path in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I did some search on what information you have provided. I found an issue open in `rspec-rails` gem. However gem doesn't matter here but fundamentally they said its context problem. When you call `with_routing` it doesn't executed in correct context, so gives error of No Route matches.

To resolve issue, I tried locally with different solution. Here is what I have tried

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe FooController, type: :controller do
  it 'does something' do

    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      root to: 'foo#index', via: :get
    end

   expect(get: root_path).to route_to("foo#index")

  end
end
```

In above code, the major problem is it overwrite existing routes. But we can reproduce routes with `Rails.application.reload_routes!` method.

I hope this helps to you!!

**UPDTATE**

I tried to understand your last comment and dig into `get` method.  When we call `get` method it takes argument of action of controller for which we are doing test. In our case when we do `get(root_path)` it tries to find `foo#/` which is not exists and hence gives no route matches error.

as our main goal is to check root_path routes are generated correctly, we need to use method `assert_routing` to check it. Here is how I test and it works 
`assert_routing root_path , controller: "foo", action: "index"`

Full code :

```
require 'test_helper'

class FooControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  it 'does something' do
    with_routing do |set|
      set.draw do
        root to: 'foo#index', via: :get
      end

      root_path.must_equal '/' #=> true
      assert_routing root_path , controller: "foo", action: "index" #=> true
      get :index
      response.body.must_equal ""
    end
  end
end
```

I read things from official document : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html

Comment: Unfortunately this still gives me `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/", :controller=>"foo"}`

Comment: FWIW, this also happens if I specify the path to get manually, i.e.: `get('/') #=> UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/", :controller=>"foo"}`

Comment: Your comment “In our case when we do get(root_path) it tries to find foo#/ which is not exists and hence gives no route matches error.” made me realize what I had done wrong that caused the error, so I awarded you the bounty. I've added a straightforward answer and accepted it for those who come across this question later. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

if you check the source of `ActionController::TestCase#get` method, it expects action name, e.g. :index, :create, 'edit, 'create'

if you pass `root_path` on `#get` method, absolutely it will raise error, because `root_path` method returns '/'.
I just checked to add :/ method to FooController

```
class FooController
  def index
  end

  def /
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'foo#index'
  get 'foobar' => 'foo#/'
end
```

when I was visiting http://localhost:3000/foobar, rails gave me
`AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action '/' could not be found for FooController):` respond

I think '/' is not permitted action on rails, I don't do research further, because I think it's very reasonable.

You may write 
`assert_routing '/', controller: "foo", action: "index"`
for current test, then you can write integration test to check `root_path` and other features.

Following are the source code of some methods I've talked above: (I'm using rails version 4.2.3 to test this interesting issue)

#### action_controller/test_case.rb

```
  # Simulate a GET request with the given parameters.
  #
  # - +action+: The controller action to call.
  # - +parameters+: The HTTP parameters that you want to pass. This may
  #   be +nil+, a hash, or a string that is appropriately encoded
  #   (<tt>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</tt> or <tt>multipart/form-data</tt>).
  # - +session+: A hash of parameters to store in the session. This may be +nil+.
  # - +flash+: A hash of parameters to store in the flash. This may be +nil+.
  #
  # You can also simulate POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, and HEAD requests with
  # +post+, +patch+, +put+, +delete+, and +head+.
  #
  # Note that the request method is not verified. The different methods are
  # available to make the tests more expressive.
  def get(action, *args)
    process(action, "GET", *args)
  end


  # Simulate a HTTP request to +action+ by specifying request method,
  # parameters and set/volley the response.
  #
  # - +action+: The controller action to call.
  # - +http_method+: Request method used to send the http request. Possible values
  #   are +GET+, +POST+, +PATCH+, +PUT+, +DELETE+, +HEAD+. Defaults to +GET+.
  # - +parameters+: The HTTP parameters. This may be +nil+, a hash, or a
  #   string that is appropriately encoded (+application/x-www-form-urlencoded+
  #   or +multipart/form-data+).
  # - +session+: A hash of parameters to store in the session. This may be +nil+.
  # - +flash+: A hash of parameters to store in the flash. This may be +nil+.
  #
  # Example calling +create+ action and sending two params:
  #
  #   process :create, 'POST', user: { name: 'Gaurish Sharma', email: 'user@example.com' }
  #
  # Example sending parameters, +nil+ session and setting a flash message:
  #
  #   process :view, 'GET', { id: 7 }, nil, { notice: 'This is flash message' }
  #
  # To simulate +GET+, +POST+, +PATCH+, +PUT+, +DELETE+ and +HEAD+ requests
  # prefer using #get, #post, #patch, #put, #delete and #head methods
  # respectively which will make tests more expressive.
  #
  # Note that the request method is not verified.
  def process(action, http_method = 'GET', *args)
    # ..... 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

> The whole point of this is to test behavior inherited by the ApplicationController.

There is no behavior in your question related to `ApplicationController` other than the fact that `FooController` inherits from `ApplicationController`. And since there's no other behavior to test here in `FooController` related to something from the `Application Controller` ...

You can test this

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

with this

```
describe FooController, type: :controller do
  describe '#index' do
    it 'does not render a template' do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template(nil)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't clear in my question, but `FooController` is literally a test throwaway. I am intending to test that a `set_token` method that is used across all actions is working.